# Checking the equality of images for button in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios5

I'm new in programming iOS and i want your help ....

Checking the equality of images for button in Xcode

i use this function but it doesn't work

```
UIImage *greenImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"];

[temp setBackgroundImage:greenImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

if ([[UIImage imageNamed:@"green"] isEqual:greenImage]){
       //do something 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are trying to solve the right problem?

Comment: Will there be other images using "green.png"? Your comparison is creating another image with the same name and comparing that to the previous image that you created. It is comparing the instance but not the name of the image used so it won't work.

Comment: omg  i didn't see it thank you so much .. now it work

Answer (score 6):

Reverse-engineering application state from the user interface is normally a bad idea.  If there's a reason why the button's image has changed, it's likely you should be tracking that information instead of trying to figure it out afterwards based on the changes you've made to the button.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: now I'm programming othello game so i need this to change the image for the button

Comment: @programmerya You might want to think of an better solution to save the state of your game, the UI is not the right place for this.

Comment: what your suggestion for me ?! if you can help me

Comment: You are mixing up the logic of the game with the user interface.  You should keep them separate.  Keep track of the board state separately, and when it changes, update the user-interface to match.  Read up on MVC.